# parent method retuns empty when used in a child class in php

Tags: php, class, parent-child

I have a parent class (`DB`) with a public method named `con()`.
This method should return whatever is inside `private $con` - which it does both inside the class it self, and from outside.

```
class DB
{
    private $con = array();

    public function add($alias, $db, $un, $pw, $desc)
    {
        try {
            $options = array(/*PDO OPTIONS*/)
            $this->con[$alias] = array(
              'alias' => $alias, 
              'db' => $db, 
              'dbh' => new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $un, $pw, $options), 'desc'=>$desc);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            /*  return error message  */
        }
    }

    public function con()
    {
        return $this->con;
    }
}
```

I'm adding connections like this:

```
$db = new DB();
$db->add('alias1','databasename','username','password','an optional short description');
$db->add('alias2','databasename2','username2','password2','');
```

Now, the `private $con` should be populated with two connections - which it is.
And the `con()` method should now return these connections - which it also does:

I put up this test function inside the `KD`-class:

```
public function aliases()
{
    foreach($this->con() as $con){    //  this should returns an array with the aliases.
        $aliases[] = $con['alias'];
    }
    return $aliases;
}
```

The following code returns: `array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "alias1" [1]=> string(4) "alias2" }`

```
<?=var_dump($db->aliases())?>
```

Now, I also created `useAliases()` as a test method inside a child class that extends the `DB` class:

```
class SQL extends DB
{
    public function useAliases()
    {
        var_dump($this->aliases());
    }
}
```

The following code returns: `NULL NULL`

```
$sql = new SQL();
var_dump($sql->useAliases());
```

Why does this happen? I expected that the `useAliases()` would return the same as `aliases()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use method `add()` from parent class to set up your connection. Now default value of `$con` attribute is `array()` because you defined it so:

```
private $con = array();
```

so you get what is expected.

If you want it to work you need to runt it this way:

```
$sql = new Sql();
$sql->add('alias','db','un','pw','desc');
$sql->showTables();
```

**EDIT**

You cannot do it this way:

```
$db = new DB();
$db->add('alias1','databasename','username','password','an optional short description');
$db->add('alias2','databasename2','username2','password2','');
$sql = new Sql();
$sql->showTables();
```

because $db and $sql in this case are separate objects. You need to do it as I showed above

Comment: I do use `add()` to set up the connection. And the connection is established. So the `$con` is populated with a connection. Othervise the site wouldn't work at all. But when I'm trying to retrive the content from `$con` by using `con()` from a child class it return empty...

Comment: @ThomasK So edit your question and show how you create object and use it

Comment: I see. Somehow I got it to work now. Of course by doing exatly what you pointed out. I was so sure that I did that a couple of times before as well, but obviously not... So, by initiating only the child class, there's no need for setting the parent class? is it always like that?

Comment: @ThomasK Yes, child class always have parents class properties and methods but you need to remember that parent constructor is not being launched automatically

Comment: Then. How would I go by when having multiple classes extending the same parent? Like. I would like to have the opportunity to create different classes for different tasks. And they all need access to the the `DB` class so they can use the `con()` method - which holds the PDO connection...

Comment: @ThomasK If you have different question you should create new question with code samples and explaining exact problem

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help. Your answer solved the problem I was asking here :)